# How to instantiate a function with a function inside using inheritance in php

Tags: php, function, inheritance

is it possible to echo a function inside another function using inheritance? please teach me how do it?

```
<?php
class Clinic extends Patient{

    function getPatientsInfo(){

        echo $this->GeneralInfo();

    }
}
$patient = new Clinic;
$patient->getPatientsInfo();
```

Comment: If `Patient::GeneralInfo()` is a `public` or `protected` function then [this will work fine](https://3v4l.org/KHnaa). Not actually sure what your issue is here or what you're asking?

Comment: thankyou a lot it helps

Comment: What do you mean by "echo a function inside another function"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if GeneralInfo() is public or protected inside Patient class then you can use.